# DateAdd Function call

Tags: vb.net, function, date, syntax, windows-forms-designer

In my Windows Form I have a textbox for number of days to add and a textbox that has a date in it... On the button click event I need to use the "DateAdd" function to add the number of days in textbox number of days to the date entered in textxbox date? Can someone give me the correct syntax I have tried this and getting a syntax error.

```
DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, txtNumDaysTAdd.Text, txtDate.Text)
```

I than need to display the answer in a messagebox in the Longdate format using the formatdatetime function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use .NET's DateTime functions to do this:

```
Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text)
Dim daysToAdd As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtNumDaysTAdd.Text)

Dim result As DateTime = myDate.AddDays(daysToAdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use DateAdd, it's only there for backwards compatibility with VB6.  Use the methods on the DateTime type instead.  In VB.NET, the keyword `Date` is a shortcut for the DateTime type, just as `Integer` is a shortcut for the Int32 type.

```
Dim originDate As Date = Date.Parse(txtDate.Text)
Dim daysToAdd As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtDaysToAdd.Text)
Dim result As Date = originDate.AddDays(daysToAdd)
MessageBox.Show(result.ToLongDateString())
```